# Printing many variables causes strange formatting

Tags: c, loops, printf

In the code below, when trying to print many variables at the same time, it  causes strange formatting.
Please check the what it print now at the end of the post and how it is supposed to look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NAME_LEN 20
#define N 2


struct submission{
    int ID;
    char title[NAME_LEN];
    int rev1;
    int rev2;
    float total_score;
};
float final_score(int a, int b);

float final_score(int a, int b)
{
    float z = (float)(a+b)/2;
    return z;

}

int main(){
    struct submission example[N];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {        
        printf("insert title\n",i+1);
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(example[i].title, NAME_LEN, stdin);
        printf("give number for rev1\n"); 
        scanf("%d",&example[i].rev1);
        printf("give number for rev2\n");
        scanf("%d",&example[i].rev2);
        example[i].ID = i+1;
        example[i].total_score = final_score(example[i].rev1,example[i].rev2);
        printf("total is: %0.3f\n\n",example[i].total_score);
    
   }
     for (i=0; i<N; i++)
     {
      printf("%d     %s   %0.2f\n",example[i].ID, example[i].title, example[i].total_score);
     }
 }
```

Example of the formatting, as it appears currently:

```
insert title
A cold morning  //input
give number for rev1
2  //input
give number for rev2
3  //input
total is: 2.500

insert title
The locals //input
give number for rev1
3  //input
give number for rev2
3  //input
total is: 3.000

1     A cold morning
   2.50
2     The locals
   3.00
```

As you can see the formatting in the table above does not appear properly.
It should look more like that:

```
  1     A cold morning   2.50
  2     The locals       3.00
```

Comment: `fgets()` keps the newline (`"A cold morning<ENTER>"`) in the buffer. You may want to remove it with, for example, `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;`

Comment: Unless you're using Microsoft's library, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Sidenote: `printf("insert title\n", i + 1);`: either a `%d` is missing somewhere, or you should remove `, i + 1`.

Comment: @pmg 35 It gives: [Error] 'buffer' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: @user18335624 sigh... `buffer` -> `example[i].title`. But there are more problems. Mixing `fgets` and `scanf` doesn't work out well.

Comment: ok thanks.  About the  `fflush(stdin)` how is the proper way if I remove that?What should be used Instead?

Comment: @pmg Without the `fflush(stdin);` it is skipping the input for the 'title' part in the second loop and was going to the `give number for rev1` part. Feel free to test it without it. I am curious as to why it behaves like that.

Comment: I understand that, the real issue is that you are using an inadequate tool for obtainig user input. Forget `scanf()` exists (consider `scanf()` an extremely advanced function only useable by people with millions of line of code written). Use exclusively `fgets()` for user input ... and, when needed, convert the obtained string to a number.

Comment: So if I use always fgets() there is no need for `fflush(stdin);`
can you please point out a post that refers to converting fgets input to a number?

Comment: basic function for converting string to a number is [`strtol()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) (there's the shortcut [`atoi()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html) if you don't care about errors)